# Determining if user is adult (discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

I am writing a Discord Bot with discord.py rewrite in the python version 3.7.3.

My Problem is that i want to check if a user is adult (over the age of 18), but i can't find anything in the documentations neither on the Internet.

Does someone know how to do this?

Maybe something like:

```
if ctx.author.is_adult():
     return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord doesnt keep track of how old people are when people create a account on discord. So its impossible to get the age through discord. You can ask the user in question to give their age through your bot.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this. Unless you want to force users to enter their age to your personal database before they can access your server. And of course underage users would just lie then as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of users who have sent a message in a NSFW channel.

Maybe it’s also possible to check if they are present in a NSFW channel but I’m not sure about that